# Which part of this is wrong?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I can't figure out which part of this code is incorrect:

```
Program TrinbarjamWinningParty;
VAR
  DAP:string;
  WNA:char;
  UPM:char;
  PDR:char;
  num1:integer;
  num2:integer;
  num3:integer;
  num4:integer;
  count:integer;
  partyAcronym:array[1..4] of string;
  votesReceived:array[1..4] of integer;
  winnerVotes:integer;
  winningParty:string;

Begin
  partyAcronym[1]:='DAP';
  partyAcronym[2]:='WNA';
  partyAcronym[3]:='UPM';
  partyAcronym[4]:='PDR';
  winnerVotes:=0;

  Writeln('                   Trinbarjam Winning Party');
  for Count := 1 to 4 do
    Begin
      Writeln('Enter Votes Received for: ',partyAcronym[count]);
      Readln(votesReceived[count]);
    end;

  Begin
    partyAcronym := winningParty;
    votesReceived := winnerVotes;
    for count:=1 to 4 do
       Begin
         if count > winnerVotes then
           winnervotes := count
       end;

    writeln('Winning Pary:', winningParty);
    writeln('Votes Received:', winnerVotes);
    readln();
End.
```

Comment: Maybe include some information on what you expect to see and what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
Begin partyAcronym := winningParty;
```

What is that supposed to do?
This `begin` does not have a corresponding `end` and should probably be removed. Also at this point `winningParty` is still uninitialized. In addition `partyAcronym` is an array, you cannot assign it a string.

For the rest: I think I could read between the lines what you were trying to do and took the freedom to tweak your code accordingly.

Note that you still have to deal with the the situation of multiple equal votes.

```
program TrinbarjamWinningParty;
var
  index:integer;
  partyAcronym:array[1..4] of string;
  votesReceived:array[1..4] of integer;
  winningPartyIndex:integer;

begin
  partyAcronym[1] := 'DAP';
  partyAcronym[2] := 'WNA';
  partyAcronym[3] := 'UPM';
  partyAcronym[4] := 'PDR';

  winningPartyIndex := 1;

  Writeln('Trinbarjam Winning Party');

  for index := 1 to 4 do
  begin
    Writeln('Enter Votes Received for: ', partyAcronym[index]);
    Readln(votesReceived[index]);
    if votesReceived[index] > votesReceived[winningPartyIndex] then
      winningPartyIndex := index;
  end;

  writeln('Winning Party:', partyAcronym[winningPartyIndex]);
  writeln('Votes Received:', votesReceived[winningPartyIndex]);

  readln();
end.
```

Comment: thanks i will check it out.......i am a beginner thats why i have problems with my coding